# Javascript pass id - view to controller -

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

This is not working in my CodeIgniter function. As I have the id and cannot get that id in my controller function. I am puzzled how to do it in Javascript and Ajax way.

This is my view script

```
<script>
 function delete_img_fn(id)
    { 
      alert(id); // It gives '1','2',etc on clicking every row in table 
      var r=confirm("Do you want to Delete");
      if (r==true)
      {
           $.post("<?php echo site_url('/admincontent/delete_portfolioimg/');?>", {id:id},
           function(data) {
                alert(data+"a");
           }, 'json');
      }
      else
      {
           x="You pressed Cancel!";
           alert(x);
      }      
    }
    
</script>
```

and i am trying to send my id through the controller function as follows:

```
public function delete_portfolioimg()
 { 
echo $this->input->post('id');exit('I am trying in controller function');
}
```

The above is not working.
I also tried the below code:

```
 window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('/admincontent/delete_portfolioimg/'.id);?>'?id="+id;

window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('/admincontent/delete_portfolioimg/'.id);?>";
```

But neither worked...
It would also help me if someone guide me how to do in ajax way out!

Comment: you want to delete data by ajax in codeigniter??

Comment: Yes, Apparently I will pass id from javascript onclick from view

Comment: show your view please

Comment: We can simply pass through view. But I want the user to choose 'yes' or 'no'  on deletion. If given 'yes' then pass the id to controller for deletion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View :-**

```
<a><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>adminassets/images/icons/deletered.png" alt="Alternate Text" onclick="del(<?php echo $result['image_id'];?>)"/> </a>
```

**ajax code is:**

```
    <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
  function del(id)
   { 
     if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
         $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/admincontent/delete_portfolioimg/" + id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"id":id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            alert('Image is deleted successfully now');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Could not delete image');
        }
    });
} else {
    alert(id + " not deleted");
}
}
```

**Controller code is:**

```
    public function delete_portfolioimg()
 {  
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
        //print_r($id);exit('Dell');
            
    $res = $this->admin_model->ch_portfolioimg($id); 
    echo json_encode($res);
 }
```

**And model code is:**

```
    public function ch_portfolioimg($id)
{    
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('portfolio_img');
    $this->db->where('image_id', $id); $res = $this->db->get()->row_array(); //echo '<pre>';print_r($res);exit('Change Portfolio Image');
    if(!empty($res))
    {
        unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/NetSach/assets/images/'.$res['image_url']);
    }
    $this->db->where('image_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('portfolio_img'); 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: i think this works. I understand the code. Let me try!

Comment: The id is not received in the controller function. I gave url: base_url + 'admincontent/delete_portfolioimg', Cant know where Am I getting wrong?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, Uncaught ReferenceError: del is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick

Comment: are you add latest `jquery.min.js` link??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229148/discussion-between-kumar-and-deepak-keynes).

Comment: I got it worked. Deleted the file from the database and also from the folder itself. The response also got it worked correctly. I will upvote now and I hope you too! lol

Comment: Thanks mate. I you will approve my edit and upvote the question so that it will be useful to someone!

Comment: Thanks mate. I hope you will approve my edit and upvote the question so that it will be useful to someone!